# Replace text in Word document with headings

Tags: c#, ms-word

In a few word documents, I've placed a "variable" (ie: #VARIABLE). I'm pulling information from a database that I would like to put at this specific place, though I'm not sure how much information. I'm using the Word.Find.Replacement method for finding #VARIABLE and inserting the queried text there. The problem is that I would like to format that text so that it is of type Heading1, this way it will show up in my table of contents. How do I go about setting the heading? Here is a snippet of my code...

```
object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne;
tmpRange.Find.Text = @"#HERE";
myReader.Read();

tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Text = myReader.GetValue(0) + System.Environment.NewLine + "\n #HERE";
tmpRange.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne;

tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

I have tried several things like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Font.set_style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);
```

Comment: in your template word document can't you set place holders with needed style? then you don't want to set style from code.

Comment: I will actually have several inputs in the Word Document, all of them with different headings. Not knowing how many I will insert though, I thought it would be best to format them as they are entered. Though, I am fairly new to C#, so I really don't know how to do what you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. You simply use...

```
tmpRange.set_Style(#your style);
```

The way I have this example though, it will apply the style to ALL of your find/replace texts. You will need to create a new range for each item selected if you want the styles to be different for each replacement.